Different ways to initialize List in .Net
What are the differences between the following ways to initialize List?
public List<int> list1 {  get; set; } // first way
public List<int> list2 = new List<int>(); // second way


First way it is a property and in second a field. You generally do not expose a field (maybe you should also read about naming conventions, which I think more important than this question).

It doesn't really matter because the auto-initialization of fields of a class is moved to the constructor by the C# compiler.
You can check for yourself if you decompile the code with a tool such as ILSpy, e.g. your code's constructor with IL
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
    instance void .ctor () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x21a1
    // Header size: 1
    // Code size: 32 (0x20)
    .maxstack 8

    // list2 = new List<int>();
    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: newobj instance void class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::.ctor()
    IL_0006: stfld class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32> UserQuery/CollectionTest::list2
    // base..ctor();
    IL_000b: ldarg.0
    IL_000c: call instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()
    // (no C# code)
    IL_0011: nop
    // list1 = new List<int>();
    IL_0012: nop
    IL_0013: ldarg.0
    IL_0014: newobj instance void class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::.ctor()
    IL_0019: call instance void UserQuery/CollectionTest::set_list1(class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>)
    // }
    IL_001e: nop
    IL_001f: ret
} // end of method CollectionTest::.ctor

or just in C#:
public CollectionTest() {
    list2 = new List<int>(); // moved here by the compiler
    list1 = new List<int>();
}

